# How to use annotations in the pages of Tapestry 5 to obtain a parameter in the URL

Tags: tapestry

I was hoping I can to do:

```
/viewname?name=123
```

I tried to use the annotation is @ActivationRequestParameter to obtain some parameters, but their was always be null.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the annotation in an event handler method parameter, it should be @RequestParameter. It won't work in other methods. @ActionRequestParameter is meant to be used in page, component or mixin fields.

Could you please post your code which uses @ActivationRequestParameter?